# Output Ruby Hash to CSV

Tags: ruby, csv

I am scraping Yelp data to gather some business information. I am able to output about 20 results for a given search term in an area (`?term=Food&Location=Orange+County,CA`).

The result is a ruby hash that is formatted nicely on my terminal. I was wondering how I could take the result, and make it to a CSV so I could then auto import to Excel.

Here is my code so far, the CSV below is what I am playing with but it hasn't done much;

**yelp.rb**

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'oauth'
require 'json'
require 'csv'

consumer_key = 'CONSUMER_KEY'
consumer_secret = 'CONSUMER_SECRET'
token = 'TOKEN'
token_secret = 'TOKEN_SECRET'
api_host = "http://api.yelp.com"

consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new(consumer_key, consumer_secret, {:site => api_host})
access_token = OAuth::AccessToken.new(consumer, token, token_secret)

path = '/v2/search?term=Session+Photography&location=Orange+County,CA'

jresp = JSON.parse(access_token.get(path).body)

jresp['businesses'].each do | business |
    if business['is_closed'] == false
      printf("%-32s  %10s  %3d  %1.1f\n", 
                business['name'], business['phone'], 
                business['review_count'], business['rating'])
    end

end

CSV.open('data.csv', 'wb') do |csv|
    csv << jresp
    jresp.each do |key, value|
        csv << value
    end
end
```

Any help or pushing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should include the data.

Comment: @DaveNewton how would I do that? How would I be able to save the data from the JSON call to be able to use and convert to csv? I asked this question because I don't know what to do.

Comment: Cut and paste it into the question so we can provide meaningful advice?